# Tensorflow Image Classification Tutorial- Setting Up Confusion Matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I am following this [images tutorial for Tensorflow](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb#scrollTo=chqakIP14PDm), but I am having trouble setting up a confusion matrix because the tutorial does not follow the X_test, y_test format that traditional examples use:

Ex:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
y_proba = model.predict(X_test) 
y_pred = np.argmax(y_proba,axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test))
print('Classification Report')
print(classification_report(y_pred, y_test))
```

How can I set up a confusion matrix based on the [tensorflow images tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb#scrollTo=chqakIP14PDm)?

Answer (score 0):

@NewtoNN
I looked over the tutorial that you provided, but I cannot find the predicted values.
You could try to first predict and then compare the true values with the predicted ones.

Try the following or something similar:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_proba = model.predict(val_ds)`
y_pred = np.argmax(y_proba,axis=1)`
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, val_ds))
```

Comment: Hi Mike, when I run the code I get the following error 'Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [480, 15]'.